# Delphi ICS upload to FTP

Tags: delphi, ftp

I can upload any file, but only TXT and CSV upload correctly, any other file uploads but it's corrupt. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code. THANKS!!! :)

```
procedure FtpUploadFile( 
  HostName: String;
  UserName: String;
  Password: String;
  UploadFileName: String;
  ToHostDir : String );
var
  FTP: TFtpClient;
begin
  FTP := TFtpClient.Create(nil);
  try
    FTP.HostName := HostName;
    FTP.Passive := True;
    FTP.Binary := True;
    FTP.Username := UserName;
    FTP.Password := Password;
    FTP.Port := '21';

    if not FTP.Open then
      raise Exception.Create('Failed to connect: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);

    if (not FTP.User) or (not FTP.Pass) then
      raise Exception.Create('Failed to login: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);

    FTP.HostDirName := ToHostDir;
    if not FTP.Cwd then
      raise Exception.Create('Failed to change dir: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);

    FTP.LocalFileName := UploadFileName;
    FTP.HostFileName := ExtractFileName(UploadFileName);

    if not FTP.Put then
      raise Exception.Create('Failed to upload file: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);
  finally
    FTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Your code, or Christian Holm Jørgensen's code? I saw this exact code in an answer by Christian. Attribution is a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the `Binary` property to True, but you are not actually putting the FTP session into binary mode on the server side, so files are transferred in ASCII mode (the FTP protocol's default mode), which corrupts binary files.

After setting the `Binary` property, you need to call the `TypeSet()` method (or, you can use the `TypeBinary()` or `TypeAscii()` method) to tell the FTP server which mode to use, before you then perform transfers in that mode:

```
FTP.Binary := ...;
...
if not FTP.TypeSet then
  raise Exception.Create('Failed to set transfer type: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);
```

This is stated as much in ICS's documentation:

http://wiki.overbyte.eu/wiki/index.php/TFtpClient.Binary

> Property used to set whether files are transferred in either binary or ASCII mode. **`Binary` has no effect until `TypeSet` or `TypeSetAsync` have been successfully called.**
>
> `TypeSetBinary`, `TypeSetBinaryAsync`, `TypeSetAscii`, and `TypeAsciiAsync` can perform these steps in one call.